# Selenium Python Screenshot problems

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, screenshot, node-red

I'm having issues with a Python Selenium script that takes a screenshot of a local Node Red dashboard for displaying a static image on an eReader I have on my wall. I've done a load of research and tried lots of different settings, it takes the screenshot every time but for some reason it is missing most of the values most of the time - The Node Red dashboard loads fine in a browser. It also works fine on sites like bbc.co.uk so I know its not a network delay issue?

The setup is on a dedicated headless Raspberry Pi4 and loading a local network based Node-Red dashboard, the screenshot is saved locally on the Raspberry Pi. There's nothing else running on the Pi.

[image: Actual webpage]

[image: Screenshot]

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

#paths/options
driver_path = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
url = "http://192.168.1.4:6335/ui/"
image_location = "/home/scripts/public/solar.png"

#set up driver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1200,825')
options.add_argument('hide-scrollbars')
options.add_argument('no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('disable-gpu')
driver_path = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(driver_path))

#load URL
driver.get(url)

#add a delay to give time for page 
time.sleep(10) #10-11secs  seems OK? 
driver.save_screenshot(image_location)
driver.close()
```

Comment: What happens if you increase the sleep?

Comment: I've taken it up to 15s with the same results .. challenge is the details are 'live' and can update?

Answer (score 0):

So after the comment by @hardlib I've been playing with the sleep settings and extending them way out and its worked, basically its taking the page way longer to lead than I ever thought even over ethernet. So Ive got it down to about 30s and it's working a dream.

For future readers - defiantly start playing with the sleep setting and don't assume when its headless it taking sub-10s to load as in my case it wasn't !